# I can't get Netbeans C++ to work, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, netbeans

I recently downloaded Netbeans and I can't get the C++ component to work properly, when I attempt to compile on of the example programs I get this error:

```
"/c/Users/*/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Welcome_1/"C:/Program Files (x86)/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf

/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('

/bin/sh: -c: line 0 `"/c/Users/*/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Welcome_1/"C:/Program Files (x86)/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf'
make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 2


BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 3s)
```

I am using the following build tools:

Family: MinGW

Base Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\MinGW\bin

C Compiler: C:\Program Files (x86)\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe

C++ Compiler: C:\Program Files (x86)\MinGW\bin\g++.exe

Fortran Compiler: C:\Program Files (x86)\MinGW\bin\gfortran.exe

Assembler: C:\Program Files (x86)\MinGW\bin\as.exe

Make Command: C:\Program Files (x86)\MinGW\bin\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe

Alternately, I've used C:\Program Files (x86)\Msys\1.0\bin\make.exe

Debugger Command: C:\Program Files (x86)\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe

Comment: Have you tried installing MinGW under c:\MinGW (or some other path that doesn't include spaces or parentheses?

Answer (score 0):

I have had quite the same problem with NetBeans 7.3 fresh install on Windows 8, using Nuwen's MinGW "distro" and MSYS. I used MSYS make,  which by the way was not automatically detected.

The strange thing that happens is this:

> "/c/Users/*/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Welcome_1/"C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk
>   QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf

As we can see, path of current project and path to make executable are glued together, and so we get an error, obviously.

What I did first is to compare my make executables' versions. I had two make executables:

1. `c:\MSYS\bin\make.exe`  -  3.81

   > GNU Make 3.81 Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc. This
   >   is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
   >   warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
   >   PURPOSE.
   >
   > This program built for i686-pc-msys
2. `c:\MinGW\bin\make.exe`  -  3.82

   > GNU Make 3.82 Built for i686-pc-mingw32 Copyright (C) 2010  Free
   >   Software Foundation, Inc. License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later
   >   http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html This is free software: you are free
   >   to change and redistribute it. There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent
   >   permitted by law.

I was pointing NB to the MSYS one, but when I changed that to the MinGW one - it all magically started to work fine.