# NetBeans C++ Looking for make utility in the wrong location

Tags: c++, netbeans, compiler-construction, build

My issue here is that I have all the proper compilers for C, C++, etc installed (MinGW), and they are functioning properly but Netbeans will not acces the make.exe util.  I reinstalled NetBeans C++ because my last install became corrupted, and I now get this error whenever I build a project:

```
"/c/Users/User/Dropbox/C++ Workspace/Project/"C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
/bin/sh: /c/Users/User/Dropbox/C++ Workspace/Project/C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe: No such file or directory
make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 127


BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 303ms)
```

The solution to this problem seems trivial because NetBeans is looking for the make.exe util in the wrong location.  The last part of the url it is searching for is correct, but it appears as though it is appending the project's location to the beginning of it.  I may be wrong though.  Does anyone know why NetBeans is doing this and/or how I can go about fixing it? Thanks!

Also, I tried the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959679/i-cant-get-netbeans-c-to-work-what-am-i-doing-wrong?rq=1), but I was never referencing any other version of the make utility except the MinGW one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have exactly the same problem with NetBeans IDE 7.3 and MinGW in that the pathname for the make file is concatenated with the project folder name; as a result the make file can not be found. After much agonizing trial and error, I finally got it working, at least for the Welcome_1 example supplied by NetBeans and my own original project that I was working on.

Remember when you first set up NetBeans it told you that mingw32-make.exe under C:\MinGW\bin is incompatible and asked you to use the make.exe under C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin ? It turned out it is the latter that's incompatible. I made a copy of mingw32-make.exe , renamed it make.exe (otherwise NetBeans refuses to use it) , updated the tool collection accordingly and voila it worked "BUILD SUCCESSFUL".

Hope this will help others in the future.

Update: just installed NetBeans IDE 7.3.1 and now "/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" works fine. So this appears to be a bug in NetBeans 7.3 that's fixed in 7.3.1. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've had excact same problem. Tried the way one post up, but it didn't solve my problem. By the way, main project compiled, but test did not (I use google test 1.7.0). I resolved this problem by downgrading JDK 7 and JRE 7 to update 17. You can download it from Oracle website. Here's a link: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html

Sorry for my English.